# Sharepoint 2013 farm analysis

Tags: 2013, server-farm

our company has just acquired a small company (~500 users) and I was given the task to generate a detailed report about their SharePoint 2013 farm. Is there a good template that I can use (just dont want to re-invent the wheel)? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you tried below mentioned tool to get farm report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a powerful tool available at below mentioned URL to get a quick overview of your SharePoint Farm.

[SPSFarmReport](https://spsfarmreport.codeplex.com/)

You can get the more information about the tool on above link.

I hope it helps you to generate quick SP farm  report...!

Comment: @Kevin Short, Did you get it working? Is above information somewhat helps you in it?

Comment: Kindly post the resolution here if you found any apart from my answer. Thanks